# Parallell download of objects from a AWS S3 bucket on iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to download download several images in parallell from an S3 bucket and I want to know once all of them has finished. I am able to perform the download of an object using a function I have written with the following signature:

```
func downloadImage(key: String) -> AWSTask
```

The AWSTask returned is this one from an instance of AWSS3TransferUtility:

```
downloadDataFromBucket:key:expression:completionHander:
```

I want to run some code when all of the downloads complete so I have tried this code:

```
for image in imageList {
    downloadTaskList.append(downloadImage(image))
}

AWSTask(forCompletionOfAllTasks:downloadTaskList).continueWithBlock {
        (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        print("All images downloaded")
        return nil
}
```

In this code imageList is a list of Strings and downloadTaskList is a list where all AWSTasks are appended to.

The problem is that it prints "All images downloaded" instantly, before the images are downloaded. I think this is because the AWSTask returned from downloadDataFromBucket is considered completet when the download starts not when it is completed. What AWSTask can I add to the list instead to make this work? I tried adding the completion handler of downloadDataFromBucket but it is not an AWSTask.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make my own task using AWSTaskCompletionSource. I simply create a new task completion source at the top of my function:

```
let taskCompletionSource = AWSTaskCompletionSource()
```

I return the corresponding task at the end of the function:

```
return taskCompletionSource.task
```

Lastly I set the task as completed in the completion handler:

```
taskCompletionSource.setResult("Download Completed")
```

The completion handler also calls setError on the taskCompletionSource in the case of errors.

Comment: Really dumb that this isn't the AWS default implementation. Spent hours pulling my hair out about this, and this was a simple fix with my existing code structure!